# ServerCertificateValidationCallback() return true but GetResponse() throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, httpwebrequest

I've created a ServerCertificateValidationCallback to check the validity of websites certificates.
Testing different URLs there is one case where I give the HttpWebRequest a URL,
GetResponse() calls ServerCertificateValidationCallback() and ServerCertificateValidationCallback() does its check and returns true.
But even though true is returned, request.GetResponse() still throws an exception which I believe means that there was an issues with the certificate.

```
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
            sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.UTF8);

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
```

How is it possible that ServerCertificateValidationCallback() returns true but an exception is still being thrown?

Comment: Please share exception details, and also some reproducible codes so that people can help you.

Comment: Note: It's better to use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) instead of legacy `HttpWebRequest` especially if you consider future migration to .NET Core or .NET 5/6.